# Stopping the Inheritance of nav-bar for a particular template

Tags: python, html, django

I working on a Django project and there is a navbar for the site. So when one user gets logged in I want to change the navbar. So how can I stop the navbar getting inherited from the base template?

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blog</title>
        <title>Eapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Eapp</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="{% url 'eapp:registration' %}">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="{% url 'eapp:login' %}">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content%}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my base.html looks like and , please give me an idea about how the new template look like? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can user django template tags e.g this is template tags which display that if user is authenticated then it will show logout button else login. same way you can do it for your navigation bar in base.html.

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Any way is there any way to stop template inhertance?

Comment: hide navigation bar when user is authenticated  e.g  in if condition do not put navigation bar code and in else you put navigation related code, which will stop your navigation bar from getting inherited.